# How can I write find-instance in def-rule in CLIPS?

Tags: syntax-error, clips

What is Wrong with this defrule as it always give me this error

```
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::print-university-info
   ?university <- (object (is-a University)
           (universityName $?name)
           (numFaculties $?num)
           (faculties ?facultyy $?faculties))
   ?faculty <- (find-instance (
CLIPS>
```

the rule is

```
(defrule print-university-info
   ?university <- (object (is-a University) (universityName $?name) (numFaculties $?num) (faculties ?facultyy $?faculties))
   ?faculty <- (find-instance ((?facultyInstance Faculty)) (eq ?facultyy ?facultyInstance))
    => 
    (printout t "University name: " ?name " Number of faculties: " ?num " Faculties: " ?faculty crlf)
)
```

the classes are

```
(
  defclass University
  (is-a USER)
  (slot universityName (type SYMBOL))
  (slot numFaculties (type INTEGER))
  (multislot faculties (type INSTANCE))
)

( 
  defclass Faculty 
  (is-a USER)
  (slot facultyName (type STRING))
)
```

and the instances are

```
(make-instance Cairo of University (universityName "Cairo") (numFaculties 1) (faculties [FCAI]))

(make-instance FCAI of Faculty (facultyName "FCAI"))
```

I checked the find-instance by adding this to clips
(find-instance ((?facultyInstance Faculty)) (eq ?facultyInstance [FCAI]))

and it returned this

```
CLIPS> (find-instance ((?facultyInstance Faculty)) (eq ?facultyInstance [FCAI]))
([FCAI])
```

Answer (score 0):

Find-instance is a function. To call functions from the conditions of a rule, you need to use the **test** conditional element. The way you've used find-instance in your rule, CLIPS thinks it's the name of a deftemplate. Typically, there's few if any reasons for calling query functions from the conditions of a rule; for most use cases, you'd call them from the actions of a rule. In the conditions of a rule, use a pattern instead:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(defclass University
   (is-a USER)
   (slot universityName (type SYMBOL))
   (slot numFaculties (type INTEGER))
   (multislot faculties (type INSTANCE)))
CLIPS> 
(defclass Faculty 
   (is-a USER)
   (slot facultyName (type STRING)))
CLIPS> 
(definstances initial
   (Cairo of University 
      (universityName "Cairo")
      (numFaculties 1)
      (faculties [FCAI]))
   (FCAI of Faculty
      (facultyName "FCAI")))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print-university-info
   ?university <- (object (is-a University) 
                          (universityName $?name)
                          (numFaculties $?num)
                          (faculties ?facultyy $?faculties))
   ?faculty <- (object (is-a Faculty)
                       (name ?facultyy))
   => 
   (printout t "University name: " ?name " Number of faculties: " ?num " Faculties: " ?faculty crlf))   
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
University name: Cairo Number of faculties: 1 Faculties: <Instance-FCAI>
CLIPS>
```